# is it possible to invoke function inside if statement only if it returns true

Tags: javascript

Im trying to is invoke function inside if statement only if it returns true. The below function checks the username field to make sure theres something in it if there is it sends it to the function validate form

```
function usernamecheck() {
    if ($("#signupUsername").val().length < 4) {

        return true;
    }
}

function validateForm() {

    if (usernamecheck(returns true)) {
        //run code
    }
}
```

Is it possible/ the best way to do it

Comment: just `if (usernamecheck())`. By the way,  add a `return false` at the end of  `usernamecheck` function would be a good idea.

Comment: And also, just `return $("#signupUsername").val().length < 4;`

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus a JS function without an explicit `return` returns `undefined`.

Comment: @Alnitak well sure, I just like to explicitely specify all possible return paths, but that's just a personal point of view (or maybe just an habit from other languages, I'll ask my psychoanalyst)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function usernamecheck() {
    //Updated this to just return the expression.  It will return true or false.
    return $("#signupUsername").val().length < 4;        
}

function validateForm() {
    //Here we just call the above function that will either return true or false.
    //So by nature the if only executes if usernamecheck() returns true.
    if (usernamecheck()) {
        //Success..Username passed.
    }
}
```

Comment: no need for braces around the `return` expression - `return` is an operator, not a function.

Comment: Your answer would be more educational if you explained what you did, rather than require the reader to go character-by-character to see what you did differently.

Comment: @BryanOakley added comments.